# Is there an easy way to detect .NET 1.1 dependencies in a solution?

Tags: c#, dependencies, legacy, .net-1.1

I'm maintaining some older .NET applications, and twice this week there have been problems when customers tried to move their apps over to new hardware (two different apps). In both cases the problem was solved by installing .NET 1.1

The question is, is there an easy way to find these dependencies in the source code, so that future versions can run with only 2.0 or newer installed? Seems like Win 7 only comes with 2.0 =< installed (and XP with no .NET, unless the service packs do?)

Of course I could make an installer and make it 1.1 dependent, but I would prefer to weed the old ideas if possible.

-Erik

Comment: I do have the source code. The question is how to detect the libraries/classes that need 1.1 to work

Comment: You'd get a much better answer if you had documented the "problems".

Comment: That's just it, I don't know what the problems were. The app ran just fine, no error messages, but when the customer pushed a certain (physical) button, something was supposed to happen (communication through an opc server), but it didn't. After installing 1.1, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you want to updates your project(s) to .NET 2.0.  I don't think there is a tool that will show you what is only .NET 1.1, but there aren't that many things that won't work after the update.  My suggestion is to do the update, compile and fix compiler errors.  Shouldn't be too many of them.